Use ibis-framework to compute shifts (lags) in dataframe
Say I want to do the following in Polars:
df.with_columns(
    a_1 = pl.col('a').shift(1),
    a_2 = pl.col('a').shift(2),
    b_1 = pl.col('b').shift(1),
    b_2 = pl.col('b').shift(2),
)

Say, starting from
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,3,2,4], 'b': [5,1,2,1]})

So, desired output:
shape: (4, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ a_1  ┆ a_2  ┆ b_1  ┆ b_2  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ 5    ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 3    ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 5    │
│ 4   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 2    ┆ 1    │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

How can I do this with ibis?
I need to do this starting from the Polars dataframe df, so I need to connect to that using Ibis. Looking at the docs doesn't give much away in terms of what I'm actually supposed to do

Is it correct to do:
t = ibis.memtable(df)
t = t.mutate(
    ibis._['a'].lead(1),
    ibis._['a'].lead(2),
    ibis._['b'].lead(1),
    ibis._['b'].lead(2),
)
t.to_polars()


you can use lag() window function:
t.mutate(
    a_1 = t.a.lag(1),
    a_2 = t.a.lag(2),
    b_1 = t.b.lag(1),
    b_2 = t.b.lag(2)
).to_polars()


shape: (4, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ a_1  ┆ a_2  ┆ b_1  ┆ b_2  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ 5    ┆ null │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 3    ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ 5    │
│ 4   ┆ 1   ┆ 2    ┆ 3    ┆ 2    ┆ 1    │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

